# How to mock org.springframework.core.io.Resource object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

In my service method, I have a dependency on `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` reference and I want to write a test case for one of service method with below code

The code below is as follows :

```
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService{

 @Value("classpath:email_template.html")
 private Resource emailTemplateResource;

 private String getEmailTemplate() {

        String template = null;
        try {
            template = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(emailTemplateResource.getInputStream()))
                    .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return template;
    }

}
```

Here, I'm not able to mock `emailTemplateResource` object in my test case method. I tried with `@Mock` and `@Spy` but each time I'm getting NullPointerException on `emailTemplateResource` object.

So, what is the right way to mock this `emailTemplateResource` object?

Comment: Can you also share your test code?

Comment: Just creating a mock isn't enough, you also have to register behavior on it. If `getInputStram` isn't registered with behavior, it returns `null`(default mock behavior) and that will propably result in a `NullPointerException` being thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You can do constructor injection in `EmailServiceImpl`. That way in your mock class when create `EmailServiceImpl` you can pass your own `Resource`  object in the constructutor.

The overhead with this approach is that `@InjectMocks` is of no use as now you are creating your object on your own inside `before` hook of the test case.

example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmailServiceImplTest{

    EmailServiceImpl  emailServiceImpl ;

    Resource emailTemplateResource;

       @Before
       public void before() {
            emailTemplateResource = //your impl here
           emailServiceImpl  = new EmailServiceImpl(resource);
       }
}
```

Comment: This is the best practice.